# PHP CURL CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ignored

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https

For some reason I am unable to use CURL with HTTPS. Everything was working fine untill I ran upgrade of curl libraries. Now I am experiencing this response when trying to perform CURL requests:  **Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)**

Following suggestions posted here on related issues I have tried to do the following:

- Disable verification for host and peer

  ```
  curl_setopt($cHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($cHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
  ```
- Enable `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and point to cacert.pem downloaded from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

  ```
  curl_setopt($cHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);  
  curl_setopt($cHandler, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/positiveSSL.ca-bundle");
  ```
- I also tried to do the same thing with positiveSSL.ca-bundle which was provided as bundle CA certificate for the server I am trying to connect to.
- Edit php ini settings with `curl.cainfo=cacert.pem` (file in the same directory and accessible by apache)
- Rename `/etc/pki/nssdb` to `/etc/pki/nssdb.old`

Unfortunatelly none of the above are able to solve my problem and I constantly get  Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) message.

And I don't need this verification in the first place (I am aware of security issues).

Does anybody have any other suggestions?

**UPDATE**

After updating to the latest libraries and restart of the whole box, not just apache which I was doing it all seems to be working now again!!!

Comment: Is you upgraded Curl library compiled against a different SSL stack (GnuTLS v.s OpenSSL, perhaps)?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. The system is Fedora 16 and it was the case of yum update really. The most annoying thing is that I don't need/want this whole validation and I can't seem to be able to simply disable it.

Comment: If you're aiming to use HTTPS for security, you'll always want to have this validation process in place.

Comment: I am aware of that, however my use case here makes it all a bit redundant. Also, I have updated curl to latest available, and php to 5.4. Now, The error message is gone, but I don't get any cotnent from curl either :)

Comment: Ha, now I get somewhere curl_errno function reports status 77 which according to the manual is CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE.

Comment: You have to enable read access for the webserver on the cacert.pem file or it won't work. Try: readfile('/path/to/cacert.pem'); in a web accessible script and make sure it prints the cert out to the screen. If it doesn't, the path is wrong, or the file isn't readable.

It's also better to set openssl.cafile setting in php.ini and use ini_get to get the path. That way the path is available to everything, not just the script you're working on.

Answer (score 327):

According to documentation: to verify host or peer certificate you need to specify alternate certificates with the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option or a certificate directory can be specified with the `CURLOPT_CAPATH` option.

Also look at `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST:`

- 1 to check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate.
- 2 to check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided.

---

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Turning off the SSL verification pretty much removes all security of SSL anyway. You should fix your PHP configuration instead.

Comment: @Scopey but sometimes you might need it on local development environments with self-signed certificates. So probably it makes no sense on non-public environments, but as reminder it is always better to have some warning in log (e.g. `SSL verification disabled`)

Comment: Put 'false' works too. This solution is working for simple cases, but if SSL is really required it no will work.

Comment: There is an error in your code. $ch must be $this->cURL. Than it works.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Return data inplace of echoing on screen
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $strURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // Skip SSL Verification
$rsData = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $rsData;
```

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem on a CentOS7 machine. Disabling the `VERIFYHOST` `VERIFYPEER` did not solve the problem, we did not have the cURL error anymore but the response still was invalid. Doing a `wget` to the same link as the cURL was doing also resulted in a certificate error.

-> Our solution also was to reboot the VPS, this solved it and we were able to complete the request again.

For us this seemed to be a memory corruption problem. Rebooting the VPS reloaded the libary in the memory again and now it works. So if the above solution from `@clover` does not work try to reboot your machine.

Comment: Make sure it's not intermittent. I had an issue with paypal and peer verification where sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't. It seemed random. Explicitly setting up the cafile path and telling curl where it was solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try below if working for you:

For SSL verification we need to set 2

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = 2
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = 2
```

For not verification we need to set 0

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = 0
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = 0
```

default is always false

Comment: Hi, question is 10 years old... and the author updated it, saying it's resolved. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you