# how to write curl PHP script with this curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to write the php script to run curl job and here is the curl query to create the ticket

```
     curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H
    "username:username" -H "password:password" --data
   '{"serviceName":"CREATE_AVENT","keyValues":{"title":
    "test","actionableevent_priority": "Minor","source":
    "TEC","requester_login": "user"}}' -k
   https://createticket.com/arsys/rest/service/createTicket
```

Here is the script I wrote in php

```
$url="https://createticket.com/arsys/rest/service/createTicket";
$field=array("serviceName"=>"CREATE_AVENT","keyValues"=>array("title"=>"test","actionableevent_priority"=>"Minor","source"=>"TEC","requester_login"=>"user"));
$data_string = json_encode($field);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/var/www/xxx/cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','username:username','password:password'));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($output);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$err=curl_error($ch);
print_r($err);
print "\n";
curl_close($ch);
```

When I execute the curl query it returns ticket ID and creates a ticket in the system.
However when I run the script it is not returning anything as well as no ticket in the system.
Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this script?

Comment: You forgot a "t" at the end of your `$url`

Comment: sorry copy past wrong.

Comment: In your curl command, you're passing username and password as header values.  In your PHP, you're passing them as `CURLOPT_USERPWD`.  Might be something to check.

Comment: What response code are you getting from the server?

Comment: Also, are you checking the result of `curl_error`? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: after adding curl_error I am getting error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: You can either ignore ssl with `curl_setopt($cHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`, but a better option would be to add a verified pem file.

Answer (score 0):

From comment, I read php code failed to verify server certificate. This is option to ignore certificate if you're ok to do so.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

I found more detailed configuration in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135834/php-curl-curlopt-ssl-verifypeer-ignored)