# cacert.pem - certificate has expired

Tags: php, curl

When I try to execute a cURL via php on my Linux machine, I get the following error:

```
SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

my `cacert.pem` is the latest version according to https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

I have the following lines in the `php.ini` file (edited):

```
[openssl]
;...
openssl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem

;...
openssl.cafile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

Details:

- **System**: Linux user 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64
- **PHP version**: PHP Version 7.0.5-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

---

Btw, I'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to this issues. I'm sure I missed something. I was looking on previous answers in here, and I still couldn't figure it out.

**Update 1** - When I use the Postman chrome application, everything is working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

curl uses a different certificates path... try adding this to your php.ini file:

```
curl.cainfo = "/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"
```

if you are still having issues, you can try to run curl in "insecure" mode by [disabling ssl verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135834/php-curl-curlopt-ssl-verifypeer-ignored) via the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST settings

Comment: Honestly, I tried to do my best to get SSL to work, with no option turned off. In the end, it works with php-fpm but not with php-cli. Something should be missing in php.ini ... So annoying... I disabled it with the parameters CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.

Comment: Tony, Could you tell us where curl is looking for the certificate by default?  I'm trying to find this information but every page I search seems to have a different answer.