# cURL if https in not included in URL

Tags: php, curl, https, php-curl

I use the following PHP curl request to **scrape** the data from a remote website:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // Skip SSL Verification
$rsData = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $rsData;
```

Now when I try to scrape the data from `https://www.dsebd.org`, I have to mention `https://` in the `$URL`. Without mentioning the `https://`, no data is retrieving. But as far I can understand, as `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is set to `0`, I can omit the `https://` from the `$URL`.

Then, why the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is not working in my case?

Comment: no that's not what it means, https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ ?

Comment: Without HTTPS, **www.dsebd.org** domain will be redirect to HTTPS (HTTP 302). To skip SSL verification for any other domains that is not redirect, [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135834/php-curl-curlopt-ssl-verifypeer-ignored)